# How to keep splitcontainer panel size to a ratio?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer, splitcontainer

I have a splitcontainer with two panels in a windows form. 
I keep the first panel twice the larger the second panel. But when I change the panel orientation to Vertical the first panel which appears on left now becomes smaller in the size(width) than the second panel. 
What I tried was this

```
 splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = splitContainer1.Width * 2;
```

But this makes the first panel larger tahan it should be.

Furthermore I tried this as the comments suggested.

```
splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = splitContainer1.Width / 3;
```

But it made the second panel area which is marked with number 1 larger. [image]

Comment: If you want a ration of 1:2 you should set one container to totalwidh / 3, no?

Comment: @TaW can you show me how to do that?

Comment: What? `splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = splitContainer1.Width / 3;` ? Or `Height`, depending on the orientation, obviously.

Comment: @Taw it does not enlarge the first panel. It enlarges the second panel. It makes the second panel twice the large as the first panel. What I want to do is make the first panel twice the larger as the first panel.

Comment: So??? If you want to reverse the ratio why not do it?? instead od 1/3 you need 2/3 then. `splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = splitContainer1.Width * 2 / 3 ;`